# Positioning and grouping SVG D3/SVG/ionic

Tags: d3.js, svg, ionic3

A D3 bubblechart. Group and position svg:circles and svg:text elements

1. the function render() creates an svg element, circle and text as usual. This function includes .exit.remove update patterns.
2. runSimulation() is executed after page opening and a createChart() function.
3. click on a circle executes runSimulation() again, removing the circle 
   with .exit().remove() etc.

Simplified code:

```
fundtion render (){

  const nodeEnter = this.nodeElements
  .enter()
  .append('svg:svg');

   nodeEnter
  .append('circle')
  .on('click',runSimulation);

  const textEnter = this.textElements
  .enter()
  .append('svg:text');
  }



this.runSimulation(){

    this.render();


    function ticked(){
    this.nodeElements
    .attr('cx', cxValue)
    .attr('cy', cyValue):
    }

   this.simulation.nodes.on.('tick',ticked);

   }
```

- On the first run the cx and cy attributes are appended to the svg:svg while the circles do not have the attributes and everything is rendered in the top left corner ( also with using svg:g)
- on the click action the runSimulation is executed a second time; now the circle gets the cx and cy attributes attached and all elements move into the expected position.

-I am looking for a way to get the cx cy attributes to the circle on the first rendering so that the parent elements do not cluster at x=0 y =0, or to get x and y to svg:svg; the shown pattern is not working and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Where do the cx/cy get generated?  Ionic NavParms has the ability to pass parameters from the calling page to the called page, so you could set them there.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.nodeElements = this.nodeGroup.selectAll('g')
  .data(this.data, node => node.nodeName);

 this.nodeElements.exit().remove();

 const nodeEnter = this.nodeElements
  .enter()
  .append('g');


nodeEnter
  .append('circle')
  .attr('fill', node => this.color(node.familyType))
  .attr('r', function (node) {
    return (node.nodeName.length > 10) ? "75" : node.nodeName.length*6;
  })
  .on('click', this.runSimulation);

let wrap = (text) => {
  text.each(function() {
    let text = d3.select(this),


const textnode = nodeEnter
  .append('text')
  .attr('id', 'text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
  .attr('dy', '0.1em')
  .attr('font-size', '1.2em');

this.settings.getValue('option1').then((option) => {
  if (option === true) {
    let type = node => node.nodeName;
    textnode
      .text(type);
  }
  if (option === false) {
    let type = node => node.otherName;
    textnode
      .text(type);
  }
})
```

Thank you for your answer, Steven. runSimulation executes a tick function that does add the proper d.x and d.y now. I am not sure why it did not work - ionic lifecycle events ?